# Connect multiple node API server to single instance Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose, database-performance

I am trying to connect two EC2 instance running Node API. For example one for main API and other for Background jobs

But I found that the DB Queries in main API slows down extremely. Also the mongod instance is very unresponsive.

I am using mongodb 3.4 and mongoose

Mongoose connection in both EC2 API Instance.

```
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { autoReconnect: true, server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 } } });
```

Comment: How would you start to reproduce the problem based on the current state of your question?

Comment: I spin two EC2 node APIs and connect to a single instance mongo.. then the APIs are extremely slow. Both ec2 are running queries and updates on mongo

Comment: I understand that. Now imagine you know nothing about your code, your setup. You just came here and read this question. You try to help, and the first step would be to reproduce the situation. Do you think this question contains all the neccessary information to reproduce the problem?

Comment: mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { autoReconnect: true }); Its still not working when i connect both API servers to MongoDB server like this